# Bamboo Paper styled marker tool

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

I develop ios drawing app. I want to implement marker tool such as in Bamboo Paper app ( https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bamboo-paper-notebook/id443131313?mt=8 ). In this app if I draw using marker and don't touch up during it I have line with same alpha:
[image]

And if I'm trying to draw using marker again I have another alpha at intersections with old lines:
[image]

How can I get the same effect? I develop app using opengl es 2.0.

Comment: Have you tried: `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);` or the other variants? It looks like this could be a blending issue?

Comment: Ok. But If I don't touch up my finger during drawing I have line with same alpha at all.